# Белый экран при попытке вывода Pdf файла на экран

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-android

Пытаюсь разобраться как сделать читалку pdf файлов в android, но в итоге на выходе получаю просто белый экран без возможности перелистывания страницы, посмотрел по логам файл получаю из базы данных, но почему то вывода нет.
Использую библиотеку

```
implementation 'com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3'
```

Здесь я получаю Url из базы данных

```
private fun loadBookDetails() {
        Log.d(TAG, "loadBookDetails: Получение URL PDF из базы данных")

        //Get book url using book id
        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Books")
        ref.child(bookId)
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener{
                override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    // Получение URL PDF
                    val pdfUrl = snapshot.child("url").value
                    Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: PDF_URL $pdfUrl")

                    // Загрузка PDF по URL из Firebase Storage
                    loadBookFromUrl("$pdfUrl")
                }

                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

                }

            })
    }
```

А здесь уже получаю по url Pdf файл из хранилища

```
private fun loadBookFromUrl(pdfUrl: String) {
        Log.d(TAG, "loadBookFromUrl: Получение PDF из Firebase Storage по URL")

        val reference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(pdfUrl)
        reference.getBytes(Constans.MAX_BYTES_PDF)
            .addOnSuccessListener {bytes->
                Log.d(TAG, "loadBookFromUrl: pdf got from url")

                // Загрузка PDF
                binding.pdfView.fromBytes(bytes)
                    .swipeHorizontal(false) 
                    .onPageChange{page, pageCount->
                        // Обновление информации о текущей странице
                        val currentPage = page+1
                        binding.toolbarSubtitleTv.text = "$currentPage/$pageCount"
                        Log.d(TAG, "loadBookFromUrl: $currentPage/$pageCount")
                    }
                    .onError{t->
                        Log.d(TAG, "loadBookFromUrl: ${t.message}")
                    }
                    .onPageError{page, t->
                        Log.d(TAG, "loadBookFromUrl: ${t.message}")
                    }
                    .load()
                binding.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
            }
            .addOnFailureListener{e->
                Log.d(TAG, "loadBookFromUrl: Не удалось получить PDF из-за ${e.message}")
                binding.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
            }
    }
```

Вот если нужно, я передаю из другого activity book id

```
binding.readBookBtn.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, PdfViewActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("bookId", bookId);
            startActivity(intent)
        }
```

И вот что лежит в Constans где лежит максимальный размер файла

```
const val MAX_BYTES_PDF: Long = 50000000
```

Был бы признателен хоть за какую-нибудь подсказку, потому что по логам все данные получены, но отображения нет, как и ошибок, разрешение write,read в хранилище firebase прописал